# IIS difference: Remove and Deploy -> Delete Site and Content

Tags: iis, deployment, safe-remove

One can remove a site from IIS by the right mouse menu.
However this gives you two options:

- "Remove"
- "Deploy -> Delete Web Site and Content"

Image: http://s2.postimg.org/iz09pe2jd/remove.jpg

What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove ==> just remove/delete the website and not the physical files associated with it.

"Deploy -> Delete Web Site and Content" ==> will remove/delete the website with the physical files associated with it.

See [this](http://blogs.iis.net/richma/archive/2010/07/03/deleting-iis-web-sites-applications-and-their-content-with-web-deploy.aspx) post for more details.

Comment: Thank you! I read that post already but it didn't really mention "Remove". But that makes perfectly sense.